# Strange class found in Android project. How to fix it

Tags: android

After check crash on fabric and firebase. I found some strange class tracked but can't see any things on source code. what happen with my project ? please help.

[image: List error]

[image: Error content]

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `ProGuard` key project when you build

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code